# Javascript, print out message when all images are clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i'm having a slight problem here with my javascript code. I'm making a game for a school project and it's about clicking(removing the fish) on fish with a fishing rod. But right now you can't win the game since i haven't figured out how to make the game stop when all the fishes are clicked(removed). Under here is my entire html code and javascript code if you wanna have a look. There is also a jsbin link where you can see the game in action with all the css and html and javascript together so it's easier for you to see what i mean. 
Do anybody know how to make the game stop when all the fishes are clicked(removed) and make an alert saying "You Won!".

Thanks

https://jsbin.com/fihebiwiqi/edit?html,css,output

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>JS Bin</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css1.css">
    </head>

    <body  background="https://guideinparadise.files.wordpress.com/2013/01/down-below2.jpg">
      <h1>Fiskaren</h1>
      <img id="fiskespo" src ="https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2014/03/24/17/07/fishing-rod-295096_960_720.png">
    <p>Sekunder:</p>
      <p id="klocka"></p> 
        <form action="html.html">
        <input id='level1' type="submit" value="Level 1">
    </form> 
        <form action="html2.html">
        <input id='level2' type="submit" value="Level 2">
    </form> 
        <form action="html3.html">
        <input id='level3' type="submit" value="Level 3">
    </form> 
        <form action="html4.html">
        <input id='level4' type="submit" value="Level 4">
    </form> 
    <form action="html5.html">
        <input id='level5' type="submit" value="Bonus bana">
    </form> 


        <script> 
      document.body.style.cursor = 'none'; // tar bort muspekaren
    $(document).mousemove(function (e) { //gör en funktion för musen
       $('#fiskespo').offset({  // tar fram bilden
            left: e.pageX + -190,  //positonerar musen på bilden
            top: e.pageY + -110//positonerar musen på bilden
        });
    });

      var b = 1; 
      for (var i= 0; i<5;i++){ // skapar en loop som skriver ut 5 stycken bilder på fiskar
      fisk(b);// länkar till funktionen fisk där bilden som ska ligga i loopen finns.
      }
    function positionering(element) { //skapar en funktion som ska göra allt random
        var x = document.body.offsetHeight-element.clientHeight;
        var y = document.body.offsetWidth-element.clientWidth;
        var Xled = Math.floor(Math.random()*1*x + 300);
        var Yled = Math.floor(Math.random()*y + 50);

        return [Xled,Yled]; //stoppar funktionen och positionerar bilderna med hjälp av funktionen randomX och randomY


    }

    function fisk() { //skapar en funktion

        var img = document.createElement('img'); //skapar ett elememt som heter img
        img.className = 'fisk2';
        img.setAttribute("style", "position:fixed;");//positionerar dom
        img.setAttribute("src", "http://res.freestockphotos.biz/pictures/16/16806-illustration-of-a-cartoon-blue-fish-pv.png"); // tar fram bilderna
        img.setAttribute("width", "200");// bestämmer bredden på bilden
        document.body.appendChild(img);// bifogar body till img 
        var xy = positionering(img); // ger xy random position
        img.style.top = xy[0] + 'px'; //positionerar bilderna
        img.style.left = xy[1] + 'px'; //positionerar bilderna
       $(img).click(function(){ $(this).remove();}); //skapar en onclick funktion som gör så att om man klickar på bilden försvinner den

    }
      myTimer = setInterval(myCounter, 1000); //bestämmer hur lång tiden ska vara (1000 = 1 vanlig sekund)
      var seconds = 0; //sekunden den börjar på
      function myCounter() {
        document.getElementById("klocka").innerHTML = ++seconds; //räknar klockan i sekunder
    }
        </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `fisk(b);` but you never use that argument...
`myTimer` misses a `var` and should be defined at the code-top.

Create a var

```
var fishes = 5;
```

use that var in your for loop (instead of `5`)
Than edit this line `$(img).click(function(){ $(this).remove();});` to be:

```
$(img).click(function(){

     fishes -= 1;
     $(this).remove();

     if(!fishes) {
        clearInterval(myTimer);
        alert("It took you "+ seconds +" seconds.");
     }

});
```

Comment: Just a question, i understand all the code you did except the:  fishes -= 1; What function does this line of code have?

Comment: @JohanWestborg that's not a function. Fishes is a variable `var fishes = 5;`

Answer (score 0):

You could work with either a global counter or add a counter to the function `fisk()` (functions can be used like objects)

Below you'll find an example that adds a variable to the function. If you prefer a glob variable instead, you can replace `fisk.counter` with `fisk_counter` - just don't forget to declare `var fisk_counter = 0` outside of your function.

For demonstration purposes, I've removed most of the code in the `fisk()` function, so you can see the changes.

```
function fisk() { //skapar en funktion
    fisk.counter += 1; // increment counter
    var img = document.createElement('img'); //skapar ett elememt som 
    $(img).click(function(){
        $(this).remove();
        fisk.counter -= 1; // decrement counter
        if( fisk.counter === 0 ) { // check if all fishes have been removed
            // GAME WON =)
        }
    });
}
fisk.counter = 0; // Add counter to function
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you actually remove the fishes from the DOM, there is no chance in you ever clicking them again once they have been removed, so you should be able to just count the clicks in a closure variable. Try something like this

```
var totalNumFishes = 5; // use this in your loop that calls the fisk() function

function gameWon() {
   // Some code that tells you that you have won the game.
}

(function() {
   var removed = 0;
   function fisk() {
      // Your setup code;
      $(img).click(function() {
         removed++;
         if(removed === totalNumberOfFishes) {
            gameWon();
         } else {
            $(this).remove();
         }
      });
   }
}());
```